# Can we trust the blender alpha or beta versions API?

Tags: python, add-on

Does the API of a blender alpha or beta version remain the same or does it change until the official release of a new blender version?

I am concerned about the compatibility of my add-ons. Sometimes I am already ready for a next blender version, before the official release. But then I am always unsure if I have to test everything again with the official release.

How do you do that?

Comment: As far as I know versions are called alpha and beta because the api could be changed…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will only speak for the beta versions, or more precise the `bcon3+` releases, the blender developer cycle has 5 phases, bcon1 to 5;

In bcon3 all the changes get frozen and the branch of the release changes from master to `blender-v<x.y>-release`, so all new features, breaking changes and features not ready to ship get "scraped" and will wait to the next release (in master) and the current release will only receive bug fixes and optimizations, so... the beta (`bcon3+`) releases of blender should not contain breaking changes of the api, but I cannot speak of the alpha versions.

Source: [Blender release cycle and of Bcon phases](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Release_Cycle#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20API%20remains%20stable%20during%20this%20phase%2C%20so%20add%2Dons%20have%20time%20to%20update%20before%20the%20release.)